# Laravel 4 Nested Controllers and Routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to call a control that is nested within a sub folder in Laravel 4?

My Controllers are as follows

```
- Controllers
    - admin
        * AdminController.php
* HomeController.php
* BaseController.php
* ArticleController.php
```

Below is the code from my AdminController class:

```
<?php

class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function showLogin() 
    {
    return View::make('partials.admin.login');
    }
}
```

In my Routes.php file I am doing the following:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin.LoginController@showLogin');
```

But I'm getting a Class not found error. Is there anything I'm missing as I can't seem to find out how to solve this problem from the Laravel 4 documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as you don't change the namespace of the controller you should be able to access it from the global namespace even if it is in a subfolder.

So just change:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin.LoginController@showLogin');
```

to:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'LoginController@showLogin');
```

The filename also needs to match the class name so change 'AdminController.php' to 'LoginController.php' or change the class name from 'LoginController' to 'AdminController'.

And make sure you do `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You answer help me , does same rules apply for models and views?

Comment: for model yes.. but for view you need to separate the folders by (.) dot.

Comment: You can indeed set a namespace for the controller, you just need to make sure to `set` every facade, model and the BaseController class into the file

Answer (score 10):

You just need to add `namespace` in your `AdminController.php` file and change name of the class from `LoginController` to `AdminController`

`AdminController.php` will then be:

```
<?php

    namespace Admin;
    use BaseController;

    class LoginController extends BaseController {

        public function showLogin() 
        {
        return View::make('partials.admin.login');
        }
    }
```

and change your `routes.php` to :

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin\LoginController@showLogin');
```

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a problem when I stored my admin controller in a subdirectory of the controllers directory app/controllers/admin

I had to add this directory to the list of autoload classmaps in my composer.json file
Then run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 2):

Adding a trailing slash to "app/controllers" in `composer.json` worked for me:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers/",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

may be its too late but one of the possible ways is to use namespaces.
here is my sample:
 routes.php :

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin' , 'before' => 'admin' ), function()
{
Route::controller('contacts' , '\backend\ContactController');
...
}
```

and on top of your backend controllers add add these lines :

```
namespace backend;
use \view as view;
```

and also add these lines to your composers.json in classmap directive :

```
"app/controllers/backend",
 "app/controllers/front",
```